# Rewrite URL to a directory to a PHP file using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am trying to do a simple rewrite rule using an htaccess file. I have this page hosted on localhost using XAMPP:

```
localhost/naveesh/services.php
```

A possible way to request this is like this:

```
localhost/naveesh/services?serv=Boat%20Dealers
```

What I am trying to do is rewrite the requests to the following URL to the above URL

```
localhost/naveesh/services/Boat-Dealers
```

I tried this but it gives me a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/naveesh/services/([^/]+)/?$ /naveesh/services.php?serv=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After some research I have tried another option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /naveesh/

# Hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^services/([^/]+)/?$ /services.php?serv=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But, it is giving too many internal redirects issue now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /naveesh/
>
> # Hide .php extension
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^services/([^/]+)/?$ /services.php?serv=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

It is your first rule ("Hide .php extension") that causes the "too many internal redirects" since it (incorrectly) rewrites the request to `services/Boat-Dealers.php` to `services/Boat-Dealers.php.php` etc. This is because the *condition* (that is always successful) is not checking the same thing that you are ultimately rewritting to. `REQUEST_FILENAME` is not what you expect it to be. (Although reversing the order of these rules could resolve this immediate issue.)

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error) for more detail on this specific issue.

However, the second rule is also incorrect (as addressed in [@Faizal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75910166/369434)).

These rules are also in the wrong order.

Assuming your `.htaccess` file is located at `/naveesh/.htaccess` (not the document root) then your complete `.htaccess` file should look like this instead:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^services/([^/]+)/?$ services.php?serv=$1 [QSA,L]

# Hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/naveesh/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Note the slash prefix on the *substitution* string is removed.

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here. Relative *substitutions* are relative to the directory where the `.htaccess` file is located.

You need to ensure that `MultiViews` is disabled, since this rule will not work as expected if it is. The request would be rewritten to `services.php` but without the `serv` URL parameter. (MultiViews is sometimes enabled on some shared servers and is the cause of many conflicts.)

Additionally, you should not really allow an optional trailing slash on the requested URL. This potentially opens you up to a duplicate content issue, since you have two different URLs (one with and one without the trailing slash) that serve the same content. There is no trailing slash on your example URL, so why include it? If you need to allow for an optional trailing slash (eg. if you have some erroneous inbound links to the non-canonical URL) then you should externally redirect one to the other instead.